# Calculate the average sum for every line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am new to shell script, and I need some help:

I have the following input format :

```
x,x,12,4,61,1,9
y,y,13,4,62,2,9
z,z,11,4,61,1,9
c,c,11,4,60,3,9
```

and I want to display for every line the average sum and the first word, for example :

```
x x : 17.4
y y: 18
...
```

So far, my code looks like this :

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$line"
done < "input.txt"
```

but I dont know how to process every line

Comment: Please tell us if the number of fields on each line of input is fixed.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use awk, it will loop the records for you:

```
$ awk -F, '{                    # set input field delimiter
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)          # iterate values starting from 3rd field 
        sum+=$i                 # sum up the values
    print $1,$2,":",sum/(NF-2)  # output
    sum=0
}' file
```

Output:

```
x x : 17.4
y y : 18
z z : 17.2
c c : 17.4
```

In case you wonder the `NF`:

```
NF

    The number of fields in the current input record. 
    NF is set each time a new record is read, 
    when a new field is created, 
    or when $0 changes
```

Comment: woooh ... worked like a charm! one more aspect, if I want to sort alphabetically  ... should I pipe -sort nk2 after that ? thanks a lot

Comment: Piping the output to `sort` is the straightforward way.